# Delphi TIdHTTPServer gradually increase memory

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, idhttp

I have a server build with TIdHTTPServer on XE6 (with default Indy 10 installation and default option set on component) for file download:

```
procedure CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\MyFile.Exe', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
end;
```

after many months (6 months) and a lot of request (less or more 1'000'000), the server process increase private memory (on task manager) over 50 MB.

Is TIdHTTPServer leaking memory?

**Update**:

in a small test application with

```
initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
```

no leak are trown

I have also tried to use FastMM dll and this is the report (My SO is in italian)

> --------------------------------2015/11/2 14:52:38-------------------------
>
> Leak di un blocco. La dimensione è: 20
>
> Questo blocco è stato allocato dal thread 0x730, e lo stack trace
> (indirizzo restituito) in quel momento era: 40678A  4087AF  408ED6
> 640996
> [IdThreadSafe][IdThreadSafe][IdThreadSafe..TIdThreadSafeObjectList][144]
> 6C996F
> [IdGlobalProtocols.pas][IdGlobalProtocols][IdGlobalProtocols.IdGlobalProtocols][4743]
> 6C9984
> [IdGlobalProtocols.pas][IdGlobalProtocols][IdGlobalProtocols.IdGlobalProtocols][4744]
> 6C99D5 [IdThread.pas][IdThread][IdThread.IdThread][732] 409F80  409FEC
> 40F4B7 [SysInit.pas][SysInit][SysInit.@InitExe][1191] 6CA144
> [WMain.pas][WMain][WMain.WMain][295] 75C6337A [BaseThreadInitThunk]
> 77AF9882 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain] 77AF9855
> [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]
>
> Il blocco è attualmente usato da una istanza della classe:
> TIdThreadSafeInteger
>
> Il numero di allocazione è: 475
>
> Dump della memoria di 256 byte partendo dall'indirizzo del puntatore
> 7EF3D2C0: FC 02 64 00 60 0F FA 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 12 7A 17
> 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 B1 D5 F3 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 E2 01 00 00 8A 67 40 00 AF 87 40 00 D6 8E 40 00 A4 88
> 40 00 8D 85 D2 00 BA 85 D2 00 15 FC 4C 00 9E FB 4C 00 05 43 4B 00 ED
> 91 66 00 5D 9A 6C 00 80 9F 40 00 EC 9F 40 00 B7 F4 40 00 44 A1 6C 00
> 7A 33 C6 75 82 98 AF 77 55 98 AF 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 30 07 00 00 30 07 00 00 A6 67 40 00 CD 87 40 00 21 8F 40 00 C6 88
> 40 00 D3 88 40 00 38 FD 4C 00 D3 88 40 00 62 43 4B 00 D3 88 40 00 3E
> 92 66 00 14 9F 40 00 14 A3 40 00 87 A1 6C 00 7A 33 C6 75 82 98 AF 77
> 55 98 AF 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 08 00 00 00 BC 69 4E 00 45 BC CB 52 A0 41 D3 00 80 80 80 80 BA 43
> 34 AD 80 80 80 80 ü  .  d  .  `  .  ú  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> z  .  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  ±  Õ  ó  ~ .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  â  .  .  .  Š  g  @  .  ¯  ‡  @  .  Ö  Ž  @  . ¤  ˆ
> @  .    …  Ò  .  º  …  Ò  .  .  ü  L  .  ž  û  L  .  .  C  K  .  í  ‘
> f  .  ]  š  l  . €  Ÿ  @  .  ì  Ÿ  @  .  ·  ô  @  .  D  ¡  l  .  z  3
> Æ  u  ‚  ˜  ¯  w  U  ˜  ¯  w  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0  .
> .  .  0  .  .  .  ¦  g  @  .  Í  ‡  @  .  !    @  .  Æ  ˆ  @  . Ó  ˆ
> @  .  8  ý  L  .  Ó  ˆ  @  .  b  C  K  .  Ó  ˆ  @  .  >  ’  f  .  .  Ÿ
> @  .  .  £  @  . ‡  ¡  l  .  z  3  Æ  u  ‚  ˜  ¯  w  U  ˜  ¯  w  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ¼  i
> N  .  E  ¼  Ë  R     A  Ó  .  €  €  €  €  º  C  4  ­  €  €  €  €
>
> --------------------------------2015/11/2 14:52:38-------------------------
> Leak di un blocco. La dimensione è: 36
>
> Questo blocco è stato allocato dal thread 0x730, e lo stack trace
> (indirizzo restituito) in quel momento era: 40678A  4087AF  408ED6
> 440106
> [System.SyncObjs.pas][System][System.SyncObjs.TEvent.Create][827]
> 412FEA
> [Winapi.Windows.pas][Winapi][Winapi.Windows.GetProcAddress][34295]
> 6C98AB [IdStack.pas][IdStack][IdStack.IdStack][1138] 409F80  409FEC
> 40F4B7 [SysInit.pas][SysInit][SysInit.@InitExe][1191] 6CA144
> [WMain.pas][WMain][WMain.WMain][295] 75C6337A [BaseThreadInitThunk]
> 77AF9882 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain] 77AF9855
> [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]
>
> Il blocco è attualmente usato da una istanza della classe:
> TIdCriticalSection
>
> Il numero di allocazione è: 458
>
> Dump della memoria di 256 byte partendo dall'indirizzo del puntatore
> 7EFA0A60: 90 D7 60 00 C0 9B 8A 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 CC A7 B0 80 80 80 80 00 00 00
> 00 91 0B FA 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D1 01
> 00 00 8A 67 40 00 A3 A4 40 00 D4 A6 40 00 D1 E3 40 00 0E B4 AF 77 B5
> 33 AF 77 E3 2F AF 77 FA FA AD 77 2B D7 C6 75 48 D7 C6 75 BA D6 C6 75
> 7E D6 C6 75 91 D6 C6 75 32 FA AD 77 1A D6 C6 75 04 D4 C6 75 FE D5 C6
> 75 34 47 B1 77 A1 47 B1 77 09 F2 AE 77 74 F2 AE 77 30 07 00 00 30 07
> 00 00 A6 67 40 00 5D A5 40 00 41 A1 40 00 4B B4 62 00 14 9F 40 00 14
> A3 40 00 87 A1 6C 00 7A 33 C6 75 82 98 AF 77 55 98 AF 77 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 B0 04
> 02 00 70 93 97 CA   ×  `  .  À  ›  Š  .  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  Ì  §  °  €  €  €  €  .  .
> .  .  ‘  .  ú  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . Ñ  .
> .  .  Š  g  @  .  £  ¤  @  .  Ô  ¦  @  .  Ñ  ã  @  .  .  ´  ¯  w  µ  3
> ¯  w  ã  /  ¯  w ú  ú  ­  w  +  ×  Æ  u  H  ×  Æ  u  º  Ö  Æ  u  ~  Ö
> Æ  u  ‘  Ö  Æ  u  2  ú  ­  w  .  Ö  Æ  u .  Ô  Æ  u  þ  Õ  Æ  u  4  G
> ±  w  ¡  G  ±  w  .  ò  ®  w  t  ò  ®  w  0  .  .  .  0  .  .  . ¦  g
> @  .  ]  ¥  @  .  A  ¡  @  .  K  ´  b  .  .  Ÿ  @  .  .  £  @  .  ‡  ¡
> l  .  z  3  Æ  u ‚  ˜  ¯  w  U  ˜  ¯  w  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  "  .  .  .  °  .  .  .  p  “  —  Ê
>
> --------------------------------2015/11/2 14:52:38-------------------------
> Leak di un blocco. La dimensione è: 36
>
> Questo blocco è stato allocato dal thread 0x730, e lo stack trace
> (indirizzo restituito) in quel momento era: 40678A  4087AF  408ED6
> 440106
> [System.SyncObjs.pas][System][System.SyncObjs.TEvent.Create][827]
> 4087B8  6409AF
> [IdThreadSafe][IdThreadSafe][IdThreadSafe..TIdThreadSafeObjectList][144]
> 6C99D5 [IdThread.pas][IdThread][IdThread.IdThread][732] 409F80  409FEC
> 40F4B7 [SysInit.pas][SysInit][SysInit.@InitExe][1191] 6CA144
> [WMain.pas][WMain][WMain.WMain][295] 75C6337A [BaseThreadInitThunk]
> 77AF9882 [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain] 77AF9855
> [Unknown function at RtlInitializeExceptionChain]
>
> Il blocco è attualmente usato da una istanza della classe:
> TIdCriticalSection
>
> Il numero di allocazione è: 476
>
> Dump della memoria di 256 byte partendo dall'indirizzo del puntatore
> 7EFA0F60: 90 D7 60 00 E8 9B 8A 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 7F C8 17 80 80 80 80 00 00 00
> 00 91 10 FA 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 01
> 00 00 8A 67 40 00 A3 A4 40 00 30 A9 40 00 26 6D 4B 00 81 68 4B 00 12
> 3B 66 00 2D 9A 6C 00 80 9F 40 00 EC 9F 40 00 B7 F4 40 00 44 A1 6C 00
> 7A 33 C6 75 82 98 AF 77 55 98 AF 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 07 00 00 30 07
> 00 00 5D A5 40 00 95 BA 40 00 DD B9 40 00 DD BA 40 00 45 C8 40 00 E9
> C4 40 00 25 C5 40 00 FA C6 40 00 9B 6E 4B 00 B6 67 4B 00 D3 88 40 00
> 7A 40 66 00 14 9F 40 00 14 A3 40 00 87 A1 6C 00 7A 33 C6 75 82 98 AF
> 77 55 98 AF 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 B0 04
> 02 00 29 94 D2 50   ×  `  .  è  ›  Š  .  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . v    È  .  €  €  €  €  .  .
> .  .  ‘  .  ú  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . ß  .
> .  .  Š  g  @  .  £  ¤  @  .  0  ©  @  .  &  m  K  .    h  K  .  .  ;
> f  .  -  š  l  . €  Ÿ  @  .  ì  Ÿ  @  .  ·  ô  @  .  D  ¡  l  .  z  3
> Æ  u  ‚  ˜  ¯  w  U  ˜  ¯  w  .  .  .  . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0  .  .  .  0  .  .  . ]  ¥
> @  .  •  º  @  .  Ý  ¹  @  .  Ý  º  @  .  E  È  @  .  é  Ä  @  .  %  Å
> @  .  ú  Æ  @  . ›  n  K  .  ¶  g  K  .  Ó  ˆ  @  .  z  @  f  .  .  Ÿ
> @  .  .  £  @  .  ‡  ¡  l  .  z  3  Æ  u ‚  ˜  ¯  w  U  ˜  ¯  w  .  .
> .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  °  .  .  .  )  ”  Ò  P

Comment: why ask here? You can find out this yourself. Make a small testapplication and set [ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) to true...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I have updated the question

Comment: Are you using the XE6 built-in Indy server, or do you use the latest available code from the svn trunk?

Comment: @whosrdaddy yep! XE6 built-in Indy server (Indy 10)

Comment: Related answer here: [Strategy or tools to find “non-leak” memory usage problems in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365483/80901) - Since September 2012, there is a very simple and comfortable way to find this type of "run-time only" memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not abnormal for long-running processes to have a memory footprint after some running-time that is larger than the memory footprint from shortly after start-up. Even when the process is temporarily not processing requests. Since memory allocations take some time, some memory managers (and I think FastMM does this as well) will keep memory that is not longer in use still allocated, ready for when the software needs to assign new objects or variables, so the memory can be re-used.

In your case, if possible, let the process run another few months and see wether the memory usage is stable and no longer keeps growing. If it's important this memory should be made available again for other processes, check if you can tweak FastMM with options or configuration settings.